# Combined contribution and event report

Tags: civievent, contributions

I have a contribution report that lists all of our online contributions. I've been asked if I can include an event field in the report (event creator) when the contribution is linked to an event. Is this possible? I've tried SearchKit, but I don't really know what I'm doing.
Thanks

Edit to show what I'm seeing in SearchKit:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get what I wanted using the SearchKit as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Contributions are linked to event participants. So in SearchKit, your main search is for Contributions, then choose "With (optional)": Participants.
From there you can link to event fields by choosing "With (optional)": Events.

Comment: There is no "with (optional)" participants under the contribution entity. However, I was able to get what I wanted - see my answer.